# Append an href link within my HTML file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

My goal is to dynamically append links on my page with the user's selection from my HTML dropdown menu using jQuery. Once the user selects their option, I would like to it to be added as a parameter to the end of the `href` URL (the URL is a link to another site)

HTML:

```
<div class= "select">
    <select name="scroll">
      <option value="1">----- options -----</option>
      <option value="2" >A</option>
      <option value="3">B</option>
      <option value="4">C</option>
      <option value="5">D</option>
      <option value="6">E</option>
    </select>
</div> 

<div class="link">  <a href="http://www.example.com"> link </a></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $char = $('.select').val(); 
   $(".select").change(function() {
   $char = $(this).val();
   alert($char);
});

$(".test").click(function(){
 $(".link").href.append("$char");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr) and [text](http://api.jquery.com/text) methods:

```
$(".test").click(function(){
 $(".link a").attr('href',function(_,v){
   return v += $char;
 }).text($char);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write change event of `select` element which is inside `.select` div. `.select` here is a `class` name given to `div`. So attach `change event` to `select`. Check inline comments to understand how it works.

```js
var $char = $('.select').val();
$(".select select").change(function() {
  $char = $(this).val();
  if ($char != '1') { //check if default option has been selected
    var link = $('.link a'); //get the reference to link
    linkhref = link.attr('href').split('?')[0]; //split its actual href and store it
    link.attr('href', linkhref + '?param' + $char); //change href with attr by combining actual href and param
    alert(link.attr('href'));
  } else
    alert('Please select an option'); //alert it its default option
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <select name="scroll">
    <option value="1">----- options -----</option>
    <option value="2">A</option>
    <option value="3">B</option>
    <option value="4">C</option>
    <option value="5">D</option>
    <option value="6">E</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="link"> <a href="http://www.example.com"> link </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.select` is not the class of dropdown. So your change event will never fire. Try like following. Hope this will help you.

```js
var link = $(".link a");
        
$("select[name=scroll]").change(function() {
       var char = $(this).val();
             
       var url = link.attr('href').split('?')[0];
       link.attr('href', url + '?param_name=' + char); 
       //use your parameter name instead of param_name
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
    <select name="scroll">
        <option value="1">----- options -----</option>
        <option value="2">A</option>
        <option value="3">B</option>
        <option value="4">C</option>
        <option value="5">D</option>
        <option value="6">E</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="link">  <a href="http://www.example.com"> link </a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot folks! I am all set. Looks like the big problem I had was not including the dropdown name in my JS.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `change()` method and use `split` method to get the url without parameters for changing the href attribute. Also use `$(this)` to catch the select that changed in the callback function.

```js
$('select[name="scroll"]').change(setUrl);

function setUrl(e) {
  //$(this) is the 'jQueryezed' select named "scroll"
  var $selectBar = $(this),
    linkContainer = $('#link-parameterized'),
    actualLink = linkContainer.attr('href'),
    newLink = actualLink.split('?')[0] + '?' + $selectBar.val();
  //Disable that the user selects the --- Select Name ---- option
  $selectBar.children().eq(0).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  //Update the href attribute in the link container
  linkContainer.attr('href', newLink);
  //Check the new link
  alert(linkContainer.attr('href'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <select name="scroll">
    <option>----- Select Name -----</option>
    <option value="john">A</option>
    <option value="pat">B</option>
    <option value="bill">C</option>
    <option value="jaco">D</option>
    <option value="miles">E</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="link">
  <!-- use id if this link it's the only one (I suppose that it's the case) that needs add a parameter -->
  <a id="link-parameterized" href="http://www.example.com"> link </a>
</div>
```

http://goo.gl/7UoZaW